# When I click any button in my view page the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

Hi I am using codeigniter In my view page I have abutton to add table row dynamically and I have a form submit button. When I click add button my form gets submitted. How to stop form submitting when add button is clicked and how to make the form submit when actual submit button is clicked.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/elfanto_css.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>


<script type='text/javascript'>
var baseurl='<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
$(function() {
    $('#test').on('change', 'input[name="pid[]"]', function() {
        var indexOfTheChangedRow = $(this).closest("tr").index();
        get_values(this.value, indexOfTheChangedRow);
    });
});


function get_values(val,rowIndex)
{
 $.ajax({
    url: baseurl + 'admin/billing/getdetails',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        val: val
    },
    success: function (indexOfTheChangedRow, response) {
        if (response != "") {
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(response),
                rowToUpdate = $("#test tr:nth-child(" + (indexOfTheChangedRow + 1) + ")");

            // add the changed row as the context to restrict the search for the classes to this one row only
            $('.description', rowToUpdate).val(json.description);
            $('.type', rowToUpdate).val(json.type);
            $('.qty_used', rowToUpdate).val(json.qty_used);
             $('.qty_prch', rowToUpdate).val(json.qty_prch);

        }
    }.bind(window, rowIndex),
    error: function (response) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
}
function loadgrandtotal() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.subtot').each(function () {
        var prodprice = Number($(this).text());
        sum = sum + prodprice;
    });
    $("#totalrst").text(sum.toFixed(2));
}


function displayResult() {
<?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
    $dropdown = form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');

      ?>

    var complex = <?php echo json_encode($dropdown); ?>;

    var row = document.getElementById("test").insertRow(-1);
    row.innerHTML = '<td><div>'+complex+'</div></td><td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="pid[]" style="width:35px;"/></td><td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="type" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_prch" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" class="qty_used" value="" style="width:45px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td><td class="subtot"><input type="text" value="" style="width:70px;"/></td>';
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
            <p><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Client.svg">   <input type="text" value=""/></p> 
                    <!-- Your Content Here -->
                        <?php

      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');
      $options_employee = array('' => "Select");
      foreach ($employee as $row)
      {
        $options_employee[$row['first_name']] = $row['first_name'];
      }
 echo form_open('admin/employee/add');  /*I open my form here*/
      ?>
            <div id="form"> 
             <!-- div form starts here.its for add table  -->
            <table id="test">
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <td style="width:80px;"><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/employee.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:35px;"><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/start_time.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:35px;"><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/id.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:145px;"><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Description.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;"><img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Type.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;">  <img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/qty_prch.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:45px;">   <img src="..assets/img/ticket_page/qty_used.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Price.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/discount.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Tax.svg"></td>
            <td style="width:70px;"> <img src="../assets/img/ticket_page/Total_01.svg"></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_employee, set_value('employee[]'), 'class="span2"');?></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="start_time[]" value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="pid[]"  value="" style="width:35px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="description[]" class="description" value="" style="width:145px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type[]" class="type" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty_prch[]" class="qty_prch" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="qty_used[]" class="qty_used" style="width:45px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price[]" class="price" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="discount[]" class="discount" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" style="width:70px;"/></td>
            <td class="subtot"><input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" style="width:70px;"/></td>

            </tr>
            </tbody>



            </table>

            <div id="add_row">
        <button onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
                </div>  
<button id="btn" type="submit">SAVE</button>/*this my actual submit button*/
            <button id="btn" type="reset">CANCEL</button>



        <?php echo form_close(); ?>  /*Here I close my form*/       
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone help me? I need to submit my form only when I click submit button. Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the `type` attribute to your button,that'll keep them from triggering a submit action when an exception occurs in the event handler.

You're using an HTML5 button element. Remember the reason it's this button has as default behavior a submit type, as stated in the W3 Specification.Check [this](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html) out.

```
<button type="button" onClick="displayResult()" class="add_r"></button>
```

Comment: @Akki619  yeah i just did! I don't understand why the down votes in the first place?

Comment: Is this question wrong? What made it down vote? And I agree with your answer and its so useful for me @psylogic I did not downvote any answers. Please verify my profile

Answer (score 0):

You could indeed change the submit to 'type' button, but in case you still want to submit the form later using the submit, don't change it.
To prevent submitting the form by default, add to Javascript:

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If you still want to submit the form, you could place the preventDefault inside an if statement.

Comment: why preventDefault is used? What is its use?

Comment: preventDefault stops the form from being submitted by default, when the submit button is clicked.